# Ignore no-member on inherited classes

Tags: python, pylint

I'm facing this while using an ODM (Object Document Mapper). It is uMongo but same issue arise using MongoEngine or SQL-Alchemy.

Basically, since classes are constructed dynamically, pylint raises a lot of false positives.

### Use case 1 : inheriting dynamically added methods

Consider this simplified case:

```
class Base():
    """Base class"""

class BusinessClass(Base)
    """The class I'm working with"""
```

`Base` gets a lot of attributes/methods added dynamically to work with a database, like `find`, `find_one`,... `BusinessClass` is just an example here, I have many of them. When using the code, all my business classes get the attributes that are dynamically added to `Base`. `pylint` does not know that, hence the false positives.

I see two ways to remove those false positives using pylintrc.

#### 1 - `generated-members`

Blacklist all those attributes:

```
[TYPECHECK]
generated-members=find,find_one,...
```

But

- I need to specify the whole list of attributes. It's a bit long but rather static. I can do it.
- Those will be ignored in all classes, even if they don't inherit from `Base` so I won't be warned if I call one of those on any random class.

#### 2 - `ignored-classes`

Blacklist the business classes

```
[TYPECHECK]
ignored-classes=BusinessClass,...
```

But

- I need to specify the whole list, which is a blocker. This is my data model. It is constantly evolving.

### Use case 2 : calling methods on deserialized fields

The framework lets me define fields, like this:

```
class BusinessClass(Base)
    """The class I'm working with"""

    name = StringField()
```

StringField deserializes to a string, so I can do:

```
`my_object.name.split()`
```

But then I get a `no-member` error as `StringField` itself has no `split` method.

#### 1 - `generated-members`

The `generated-members` solution does not apply here. I can't list all the methods of all simple types (string, int,...) and business objects provided by custom fields. I might as well remove the whole `no-member` rule.

#### 2 - `ignored-classes`

I could list all existing fields in `ignored-classes` but that would be a bit of a chore.

### What I would like to do

Ideally, I would write

```
[TYPECHECK]
ignored-classes=Base,Field
```

and `pylint` would also ignore child classes.

This way,

- I don't have a long list of attributes that are ignored on all classes, even those that do not inherit from `Base` of `Field`.
- I don't have to maintain a list of business classes and field classes.

Is this possible?

If not, wouldn't this make a lot of sense? I'm pretty sure `pylint` could technically do that.

Or is there an alternative way I have missed?

Currently, the best solution I found is to use `generated-members` in case 1 (listing all special methods provided by framework) and `ignored-classes` in case 2 (listing all fields provided by the framework).

Comment: Wondering what you ended up going with.

Comment: I ended up doing nothing and living with it. I think the proper way is to create a dedicated pylint extension.